# What is the difference in domain usage when listening to a socket?

Tags: sockets, go, tcp, listener

I came across some differences between some examples that I looked at, and realized that some use domains and some do not. What is the real difference between the two?

```
net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8080")
```

Comment: `:8080` will almost certainly mean `0.0.0.0:8080`, which listens at all interfaces. `localhost:8080` will be `127.0.0.1:8080`, which only listens at 127.0.0.1, so is only connectable to from within the same host.

Answer (score 1):

it's has default parameter, means 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, localhost. it's just convenient.

```
net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
```

Here you can hard bind any domain.

```
net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8080")
```

Comment: Don't forget that most hosts are ipv6 capable now, so these are often `[::]` and `[::1]` respectively.